# Prevent OnItemSelectedListener from being called in response to setSelection

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner, android-spinner

Whenever I call `setSelection` for my spinners, I `OnItemSelectedListener` is called. In some specific cases it breaks my app. In other words, this has to stop happening. The problem is that `OnItemSelectedListener` seems to be called through the message queue. A trivial solution doesn't work:

```
private void setCurrentItem(int id) 
{
    m_bControlChanging = true;
    sp.setSelection(adapter.ordById(id));
    m_bControlChanging = false;
}

private class SpinnerItemSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> view, View textView, int ord, long arg3) {

        if (m_bControlChanging)
            return;

        // Do work...
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you app crash cause of this it means that you got something going wrong in your application. You should try to bypass the problem, but try to resolve it at the source. Can you give us more information about the error ?

Comment: I didn't say my app crashes, I said `OnItemSelectedListener` breaks it. Describing the problem would take too long. So far I don't see any way to circumvent the issue. One way or another `OnItemSelectedListener` is the source.

Comment: I am currently making an app and using a spinner and all works fine.
Can you maybe show us the way you link them ? I mean how you set the adapter etc.

Comment: Do you mean that `setSelection` doesn't invoke listener in your app?
My initialization is very simple:
`m_adapter = new AdapterString(context);
m_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);
m_spShutterSpeed.setAdapter(m_adapter);
m_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Listener());`

Comment: something like 
    List<String> array_spinner = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  profils = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProfils);
  profils.setAdapter(adapter);
  profils.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
  {public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {}
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will not work, because the flag gets reset before you test it. You need a handshaking solution, viz:

```
private void setCurrentItemInCbCS(int ct, int id) 
{
    m_bControlChanging = true;
    sp.setSelection(adapter.ordById(id));
}

private class SpinnerItemSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> view, View textView, int ord, long arg3) {
        boolean b = m_bControlChanging;
        m_bControlChanging = false;

        if (b)
            return;

        // Do work...
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Clad Clad, but if you want to ignore the callback you can 'remeber' the last manually set selection and ignore it in callback.

for example:

```
private int lastManuallySetSelection = -1;

private void setCurrentItemInCbCS(int ct, int id) 
{
    sp.setSelection(lastManuallySetSelection = adapter.ordById(id));
}

private class SpinnerItemSelected implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> view, View textView, int ord, long arg3) {

    if (ord == lastManuallySetSelection) {
        lastManuallySetSelection = -1;
        return;
    }

    // Do work...
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
}
```